# Receiving String from RFCOMM on PC, sent from Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rfcomm

Im trying to get one string from phone (Android 2.3.3), sent to PC (Windows 7), im using RFCOMM basic connection, something like this

```
BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.i("bluetooth", e.getMessage());
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
```

and for output strings, something like this

```
String message = "TEST";
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(mensaje.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("bluetooth", "ERROR: "+e);
        }
```

And it basically works (Tried using HyperTerminal). What I would like to do is simply receive the string "TEST" on my PC, **but with an java application**, that later will control an microcontroller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to start with a Java Bluetooth application: I've had great success with [BlueCove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/wiki/Documentation) for Windows.

Comment: no, I already have working the part of sending the string from the phone, I just want to know how to get the OutputStream sent by RFCOMM.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the PC or mobile? If [you want to do this on the mobile read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer)

Comment: Im sending string with android mobile, and i want to Receive string on  PC.

Comment: So the answer I gave will work for you, see an example [here on how to use BlueCove](http://www.miniware.net/articles/viewarticle.php?id=22)